# TypeORMError: Entity metadata for xxxxxx#yyyyyy was not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've decided to create a separate repository for my TypeORM entities. After creating this repository, I installed it in my other projects using npm. However, when I start one of my projects, it throws an error like this:

TypeORMError: Entity metadata for 'Account#Campaign' was not found. Please check if you've specified the correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.

Here is how I want to create a connection:

```
export async function getConnection(): Promise<DataSource> {
  if (!connection) {

    const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: process.env.MYSQL_HOSTNAME,
      port: +process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
      username: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
      entities: [
        Account,
        Campaign,
        User
      ],
      extra: {
        connectionLimit: 5,
      },
    });


    connection = await AppDataSource.initialize()
      .then(async (_con) => {
        console.log("Data Source has been initialized!")
        return _con;
      })
    return connection;
  }

  return connection;
}
```

I tried moving all the entities into one folder within my package's code, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Please provide the code for entity files too, as errors like this one often occur due to the misuse of typeorm decorators i.e `@Entity(...)`, `@Repository(...)`